# Why is my merge sort not behaving like a O (n * lg n))?

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, sorting

I implement this merge sort based on pseudo-code available on [Cormen's Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms). I'm reproducing it, since it's short:

```
void merge(vector<double> &array, int start, int mid, int end) {
    int i = start;
    int j = mid + 1;
    int k = start;
    vector<double> b(array.size());

    while (i <= mid && j <= end) {
        if (array[i] <= array[j])
            b[k++] = array[i++];
        else
            b[k++] = array[j++];
    }

    while(i <= mid)
        b[k++] = array[i++];

    while(j <= end)
        b[k++] = array[j++];

    for (k = start; k <= end; k++)
        array[k] = b[k];
}
```

This part should be O(n)

and this other should be O(n*lg n) , where lg is log on 2 base

```
void mergeSort(vector<double> &array, int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
        int mid = (end - start) / 2 + start;
        mergeSort(array, start, mid);
        mergeSort(array, mid + 1, end);
        merge(array, start, mid, end);
    }
}
```

I made some experiments with random vector instances of sizes: 1000(10^3), 10000(10^4), 50000(5*10^4), 100000(10^5), 250000(2.5*10^5), 500000(5*10^5). With 30 instances in each size.
This are the average result I had for each instance size:

```
1000 - ~0.000 s
10000 - 0.344 s
50000 - 20.456 s
100000 - 59.083 s
250000 - 360.814 s
500000 - 1729.245 s
```

All elapsed times I take from linux time command (take users time) when running my merge sort.
As visible, it's not a O(n*lg n) behavior. What I'm missing here?
I don't know if it's relevant but my system configurations are:

```
OS: Fedora 18 - 64 bits
Processor: Intel® Core™ i3 CPU M 380 @ 2.53GHz × 4
Memory: 2.8 Gi
```

B

Comment: Did you run debugged code or optimized code? The difference can be huge because some of your loops could be parallelized. Theoretically, the algorithm `merge` is `O(n)` in terms of comparisons: but you do much more than that. You do a ton of accessing, incrementing, assignment, and you even allocate a new vector. All this eats away at performance (more specifically, poorly cached memory and cold memory hurts performance).

Comment: Try changing `vector<double> b(array.size());` for `vector<double> b(end-start);`, and use `k=0`. Your `b` is much bigger than it should be, not sure that is the problem.

Comment: That is probably your problem, `vector` fill construction has linear time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the culprit:

```
vector<double> b(array.size());
```

Suppose you start with a vector of half a million entries. That initial call to `mergeSort` is going to call `mergeSort` on a vector of half a million entries, but only have it sort the first 250,000 elements. (Then it will repeat on the next half.) The next call to `mergeSort` is going to receive that full 500,000 element array and call `mergeSort` to use sort the first and then second 125,000 elements of the array. And so on. Each time along the way, `mergeSort` will be receiving that vector of half a million entries, but only sorting a subset. Eventually you'll be calling `merge`, where a temporary array of half a million elements will be allocated and initialized on each every call.

The result is n<sup>2</sup>*log(n) behavior. That's not exponential behavior, but still it's not good.

I see three different solutions:

- Allocate that temporary `b` once and pass it as an argument to `mergeSort` and `merge`.
- Allocate a temporary array in `merge` that is of size `end-start+1`. Now you'll have to use offsets to deal with the fact that `b[0]` corresponds to `array[start]`.
- Merge in place. You don't need a temporary here. However, this is nontrivial and will make the algorithm an O(N*(log(N))^2) algorithm.

Comment: Just pointing out that in-place merge is non-trivial (although possible) and makes the algorithm slower.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the [relocation of the vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064559/how-is-vector-implemented-in-c) are taking much of the time. Adding to vectors are not O(1) operations. Try to change the vector to a basic C type array, and you will notice the difference. Also, what I see from the values, it is no way exponential. A higher polynomial maybe.