# Why can multiple std vectors be used in a class?

Tags: c++, class

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15430925/12666158), I am led to believe that the members of a class are guaranteed to be contiguous in memory, in the order that they are declared. However, from [the docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), "vectors use contiguous storage locations for their elements". So then how is it possible to have multiple vectors in a class, or a vector that is not the last member of a class, given that a vector may resize and spill over into memory that is already allocated?

Comment: Relevant question: [How is vector implemented in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3064559/580083).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::vector` is usually implemented as three pointers. One pointer to a dynamically allocated array that stores the `vector`'s contents, one pointer to the end of the used memory and one pointer to the end of the allocated array. No matter how the `vector` is allocated, the `vector`'s data is stored elsewhere in dynamic storage.

Answer (score 1):

The memory used by each vector is dynamically allocated.