# Calling constructor from another constructor?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I created three classes: `Shape` (base class) , `Rectangle` and `Square`. I tried to call `Shape`'s constructor from `Rectangle`'s and `Square`'s constructors, but the compiler shows errors.

Here is the code:

```
class Shape{
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    Shape(double xx, double yy) {x=xx; y=yy;}
    virtual void disply_area(){
        cout<<"The area of the shape is: "<<x*y<<endl;
    }
};
class Square:public Shape{
public:
    Square(double xx){ Shape(xx,xx);}
    void disply_area(){
        cout<<"The area of the square is: "<<x*x<<endl;
    }
};
class Rectnagel:public Shape{
    public:
        Rectnagel(double xx, double yy){ Shape(xx,yy);}
    void disply_area(){
        cout<<"The area of the eectnagel is: "<<x*y<<endl;
    }
};
int main() {
    //create objects
    Square      sobj(3);
    Rectnagel   robj(3,4);
    sobj.disply_area();
    robj.disply_area();
    system("pause");;//to pause console screen, remove it if u r in linux
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas or suggestion to modify the code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explicitly calling a constructor in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827552/explicitly-calling-a-constructor-in-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ superclass constructor calling rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/c-superclass-constructor-calling-rules)

Comment: Instead of commenting your `system("pause";)` hack, replace it with something portable. See http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To construct a base from a child you do the following

```
//constructor
child() : base()   //other data members here
{
     //constructor body
}
```

In your case

```
class Rectangle : public Shape{
    public:
        Rectangle(double xx, double yy) : Shape(xx,yy)
        {}

    void display_area(){
        cout<<"The area of the eectnagel is: "<<x*y<<endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: But you can't be *that* pedantic, you didn't correct "The area of the eectnagel is:" ;)

Comment: Well not of the string literal, I assumed that was intentional :D

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct way to do it:

```
class Square:public Shape{
public:
    Square(double xx) : Shape(xx,xx){}
    void disply_area(){
        cout<<"The area of the square is: "<<x*x<<endl;
    }

};
```

Look up the [superclass constructor calling rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/c-superclass-constructor-calling-rules).